# Drawing a line between the previous end point to next start point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-graphics

i'm stuck at this problem.  I need to draw a line between the previous end point to next start point. My code for drawing a line between 2 points is

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef c=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 4.0);
    CGFloat red[4]={0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 50.0f, 50.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 100.0f, 100.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(c) ;
}
```

How can i give multiple points, so that i can it shows like a graph. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add more `CGContextAddLineToPoint` calls

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef c=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 4.0);
    CGFloat red[4]={0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 50.0f, 50.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 100.0f, 100.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 120.0f, 80.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 140.0f, 120.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 160.0f, 80.0f);
    ...

    CGContextStrokePath(c) ;
}
```

Comment: thanks man, 90% solved. But, i getting x,y values from array. so how can i implement that array into these coordinates.

Comment: you need to use for loop:  
`CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 50.0f, 50.0f);  
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)  
{  
    CGPoint point = [array objectAtIndex:i];  
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, point.x, point.y);  
}`

Answer (score 3):

On a side note, Apple prefers that you use the higher UIKit methods instead of the Core Graphics calls for simple stuff like drawing lines and curves, so you could rewrite your method like this:

```
[[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(50.0, 50.0)];
[linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
[linePath setLineWidth:4.0];
[linePath stroke];
```

Comment: Yes, UIBezierPath is slower for really complex stuff but for a few lines it is easier to use and just as powerful as CG drawing.  Also, there are more prebuilt options (like rounded rect and closePath, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Jus a little correction to your code:

```
-(void)drawLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.image.size);
    [YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.image.size.width, YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.image.size.height)]; 
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    [YOUR_IMAGEVIEW setImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

**YOUR_IMAGEVIEW is an outlet to your imageview you are drawing on.**

As you can see - you just have to send to this method your start point and the end one! Easy as 1-2-3.

EDIT 1

How to use it? Declare a global CGPoint "startPoint";

Then say:

```
//___________________________________________________
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    startPoint = [touch locationInView:YOUR_IMAGEVIEW];
}
//___________________________________________________
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint nextPoint = [touch locationInView:YOUR_IMAGEVIEW];
    [self drawLineFromPoint:startPoint toPoint:nextPoint];
    startPoint = nextPoint;
}
```

EDIT 2

Here is another way to draw your points:

```
- (void)drawGraphMethod{
    NSMutableArray *pointsArr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
    //now you should add the needed points to your array
    //I have no idea what graph do you have, so I just
    //put there some random points that will look like a graph
    [pointsArr addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(30.0, 10.0)]];
    [pointsArr addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(40.0, 26.0)]];
    [pointsArr addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(70.0, 55.0)]];
    [pointsArr addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(80.0, 88.0)]];
    [pointsArr addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(90.0, 33.0)]];
    [pointsArr addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(130.0, 100.0)]];
    //well, you can store only objects, that's why I used NSValue.
    //it's not hard to cenvert it back

    //now parse the array
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsArr.count-1; i++) {
        CGPoint startPoint = [[pointsArr objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint nextPoint = [[pointsArr objectAtIndex:i+1] CGPointValue];
        [self drawLineFromPoint:startPoint toPoint:nextPoint];
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain me a little bit more plz... Like why YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.

Comment: thanks man, but user dont have a choice to touch n draw. it will automatically dobe by itself when view is opened.

Comment: well, somehow you are getting those points - the path of your curve, aren't you?

Comment: I just implemented the path in the touchesMoved, but you can define your path-points some other way. and the method will draw the lines

Comment: yes bro, how can i integrate the points to that code, google mentioned to get all the points in one array like that.. i really dont know man. Can u help me

Comment: first of all: what are you drawing?

Comment: I want to show graph like joining one point to another point, another point to some other point with straight lines, So that it looks like a graph.

Comment: so it means you already have the points of the graph? maybe you do not have the points, but you have the data of the graph, don't you? if so, just make an array, fill it with all the points, then parse the array, extract at each iterration 2 close points and use them to call my method. at each itteration, the second point from the previous will the the first from the current one.

Comment: omg...plz plz u write the code here plz... dont mind brother... Plz

Comment: Here, take a look to my EDIT 2